# Исправить ошибку в коде. Классы, перегрузка операторов, дружественные функции

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить эти ошибки в коде: класс "Matrix" не содержит подходящий конструктор копий.
Инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "Matrix" в "Matrix"
"Ругается" в строчках `Matrix m3 = m1 + m2;` и `Matrix m4 = m1 & m2;` на переменную m1

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    int size;
    int **matrix;
    friend void Show(Matrix &);
    friend void get_matrix(Matrix &);
public:
    Matrix(int N);
    Matrix(Matrix &);
    Matrix operator+ (const Matrix&);
    Matrix operator& (const Matrix&);

};
Matrix::Matrix(int N)
{
    size = N;
    matrix = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[size];
}


Matrix::Matrix(Matrix &obj)
{
    size = obj.size;
    matrix = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = obj.matrix[i][j];
}

void Show(Matrix &Obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Obj.size; j++)
            cout << Obj.matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void get_matrix(Matrix &Obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Obj.size; j++)
        {
            cout << "wwedi[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "] element matrici: ";
            cin >> Obj.matrix[i][j];
        }
}
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &Obj)
{
    Matrix result(*this);
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Obj.size; j++)
            result.matrix[i][j] += Obj.matrix[i][j];
    return result;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator&(const Matrix &Obj)
{
    Matrix result(*this);
    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Obj.size; j++)
            result.matrix[i][j] *= Obj.matrix[j][i];
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Wwedi razmer: ";
    cin >> N;

    Matrix m1(N);
    get_matrix(m1);

    Matrix m2 = m1;
    get_matrix(m2);
    Show(m1);
    cout << endl;
    Show(m2);
    cout << endl;
    Matrix m3 = m1 + m2;

    Show(m3);
    Matrix m4 = m1 & m2;
    Show(m4);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Допишите `const` к аргументу копирующего конструктора... https://ideone.com/wCILdK Да, если не хотите потом неприятностей - создайте соответствующий оператор присваивания...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, тут у вас

```
Matrix m3 = m1 + m2;
```

после сложения образуется временная матрица (rvalue), а в конструкторе копирования, который вызывается для `m3`, говорится, что вы будете ее изменять. Да, вы не меняете ее реально, но говорите компилятору, что это может быть.

Вам надо просто объяснить ему, что никакого изменения не будет, что конструктор копирования имеет вид

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &obj)
```

я все встанет на свои места.

Но только у вас могут в будущем начаться проблемы, если вы не напишете правильный, с глубоким копированием оператор присваивания. А еще - если не хотите утечек памяти - правильный же деструктор...

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, а может подскажите, как сделать деструктор для этого кода?

Comment: Просто освободить память в обратном порядке. Сначала в цикле `matrix[i]`, потом сам `matrix`...